# Bullet Physics Hello World in QT on Mac

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I'm having a problem creating a hello world Bullet project using QT on Mac. The Bullet libraries have been built and I am using the Hello World code [found here](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World)

Here is what the compile outputs:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_maxdot_large(float const*, float const*, unsigned long, float*)", referenced from:
  __ZL17convexHullSupportRK9btVector3PS0_iS1_ in libBulletCollision.a(btConvexShape.o)
  btPolyhedralConvexShape::batchedUnitVectorGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin(btVector3 const*, btVector3*, int) constin libBulletCollision.a(btPolyhedralConvexShape.o)
  btPolyhedralConvexShape::localGetSupportingVertexWithoutMargin(btVector3 const&) constin libBulletCollision.a(btPolyhedralConvexShape.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [helloWorldBullet.app/Contents/MacOS/helloWorldBullet] Error 1
12:45:12: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project helloWorldBullet (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

The project finds the libraries fine but it giving me this error. I looked in the Bullet Libraries through Terminal and it says maxdot_large is undefined.

Anyone had this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Bullet are you using, and are you linking the LinearMath library?

Comment: I'm using 2.81 and I am linking the LinearMath library. It turns out that the libraries were not built correctly. I just used CMAKE to build the bullet libraries and it works great now :) Thanks for your help!